# How to shutdown raspberry pi over ssh

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am accessing my raspberry pi 3 from ssh. Can you tell me how to shut it down from ssh. Whenever I use `sudo shutdown -h now` the terminal just freezes without any output. If I kill the terminal I can ssh into raspberry again showing it did not shut down.

Comment: What happens if you try running the same command locally?

Answer (score 5):

Add the -P flag:

```
sudo shutdown -h -P now
```

Comment: same thing happens

Answer (score 1):

`sudo shutdown -h now` or `sudo halt`

You can’t use shutdown (or halt) unless you have sudo privileges.

-h instructs to halt the system, now means to run command right now. You can add a number X to tell it to shut down in X minutes. It also allows a specific time in this format XX:XX (note this is in 24 hour format seperated by a : colon).

Comment: That is unlike the reason for described behavior, you'd get an error message about failed attempt. Moreover, the OP literally mentions to be using the same command you're recommending attempting to elevate privileges for the call.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command  `systemctl poweroff`

You will then be asked to authenticate yourself and enter your password. For reasons I don't know, it asks you to enter your password a second time.

Once authenticated, enter  `poweroff`  and the pi will shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo halt` should be help you in this case

Answer (score 0):

Just run sudo halt and wait until the green light turns off to power it off.

Comment: The green light doesnot turn off even after a long amount of time. Also I can ssh into raspberry again after `sudo halt`

Comment: That's weird, i don't know if this would work but try: sudo halt > text.txt and read the file so you can know what's happening

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, you should try:

```
sudo shutdown -h now && exit
```

Comment: same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to launch the shutdown in the background, with some delay to allow the user to safely exit the ssh connection.

Something like this :

```
{(sleep 5; sudo halt;) &}; exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I created as script to suspend or shutdown a remote host over ssh. This may be used to suspend / shutdown a remote computer without an interactive session and yet not keep a terminal busy. You will need to give permissions to the remote user to shutdown / suspend using `sudo` without a password. Additionally, the local and remote machines should be set up to SSH without an interactive login. The script is more useful for suspending the machine as a suspended machine will not disconnect the terminal.

```
local_user@hostname:~$ ssh remote_user@remote_host "screen -d -m sudo pm-suspend"
```

source: [कार्यशाला (Kāryaśālā)](https://bharath.lohray.com/weblog/suspending-a-computer-over-ssh/)